# Flatten JSON string in dataframe column with multiple rows or transfer to other df

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe in `jupyter notebook` with following columns:

```
id_pedido   filial  transportadora  cep endereco    regiao  data_despacho   peso    numero_skus source  delivery_combinations   delivery_options
```

Each row of column "delivery_combionations" have a JSON string like this:

> [{"cost": 10.81, "default": true, "position": 3, "calculator":
> "EconomyCalculatorWithQuotationDifference", "deliveries":
> [{"delivery_items": [{"id": 139083369, "quantity": 1}],
> "delivery_rates": [{"cost": 10.81, "selected": true, "carrier_cost":
> 10.1, "initial_cost": 10.81, "quotation_id": 13125739277, "delivery_note": null, "cd_business_days": 1, "shipping_carrier":
> "Sequoia Transportadora", "shipping_service": "Sequoia Redespacho -
> PE", "quotation_difference": 0.0, "estimate_business_days": 15,
> "external_delivery_method_id": 9279,
> "estimate_transit_time_business_days": 14}], "stock_location":
> "Recife", "stock_location_external_id": 9}], "initial_cost": 10.81,
> "combination_id": 164762042, "delivery_method": "economy",
> "estimate_business_days": 15, "estimate_delivery_date": "15/10/20"},
> {"cost": 41.71, "default": false, "position": 4, "calculator":
> "ExpressCalculator", "deliveries": [{"delivery_items": [{"id":
> 139083369, "quantity": 1}], "delivery_rates": [{"cost": 41.71,
> "selected": true, "carrier_cost": 38.98, "initial_cost": 41.71,
> "quotation_id": 13125730459, "delivery_note": null,
> "cd_business_days": 1, "shipping_carrier": "JadLog",
> "shipping_service": "JadLog Standard", "quotation_difference": 0.0,
> "estimate_business_days": 9, "external_delivery_method_id": 22,
> "estimate_transit_time_business_days": 8}], "stock_location":
> "Extrema", "stock_location_external_id": 3}], "initial_cost": 41.71,
> "combination_id": 164762042, "delivery_method": "express",
> "estimate_business_days": 9, "estimate_delivery_date": "06/10/20"}]

Since each row has its own json string, I would like to create columns for each field and add the values ​​for each row. I tried several methods.

Using ast.literal_eva I got the error:

```
malformed node or string: <_ast.Subscript object at 0x7f414c2eb190>
```

Using json.loads I got the error:

```
Expecting ',' delimiter: line 1 column 16383 (char 16382)
```

Is there any way to flatten this in other columns or append that in another dataframe?

Comment: have you tried `pd.json_normalize`?

Comment: @dfundako yes, and i received the following error: 'str' object has no attribute 'values'

Comment: that json in your example is valid but maybe your actual data has some error - run json lint on it .. json.loads works for any valid json.

Comment: @ZipersonSilva Change your `null` values to `None`, your `true/false` to `True/False` and see what happens. You need valid values in there for json to parse. It is treating `null/true/false` as unquoted strings most likely

Comment: @dfunkako thanks for the answer. I made this, but i got another error " 'str' object has no attribute 'values' when i try to run json_normalize :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first need to modify the `true/false/null` values in your json. Those are being treating as unrecognized variable names since they are unquoted. If you convert them to `True/False/None`, `pd.json_normalize` will parse it fine:

```
val = [{
    "cost": 10.81,
    "default": True,
    "position": 3,
    "calculator": "EconomyCalculatorWithQuotationDifference",
    "deliveries": [{
            "delivery_items": [{
                    "id": 139083369,
                    "quantity": 1
                }
            ],
            "delivery_rates": [{
                    "cost": 10.81,
                    "selected": True,
                    "carrier_cost": 10.1,
                    "initial_cost": 10.81,
                    "quotation_id": 13125739277,
                    "delivery_note": None,
                    "cd_business_days": 1,
                    "shipping_carrier": "Sequoia Transportadora",
                    "shipping_service": "Sequoia Redespacho - PE",
                    "quotation_difference": 0.0,
                    "estimate_business_days": 15,
                    "external_delivery_method_id": 9279,
                    "estimate_transit_time_business_days": 14
                }
            ],
            "stock_location": "Recife",
            "stock_location_external_id": 9
        }
    ],
    "initial_cost": 10.81,
    "combination_id": 164762042,
    "delivery_method": "economy",
    "estimate_business_days": 15,
    "estimate_delivery_date": "15/10/20"
}, {
    "cost": 41.71,
    "default": False,
    "position": 4,
    "calculator": "ExpressCalculator",
    "deliveries": [{
            "delivery_items": [{
                    "id": 139083369,
                    "quantity": 1
                }
            ],
            "delivery_rates": [{
                    "cost": 41.71,
                    "selected": True,
                    "carrier_cost": 38.98,
                    "initial_cost": 41.71,
                    "quotation_id": 13125730459,
                    "delivery_note": None,
                    "cd_business_days": 1,
                    "shipping_carrier": "JadLog",
                    "shipping_service": "JadLog Standard",
                    "quotation_difference": 0.0,
                    "estimate_business_days": 9,
                    "external_delivery_method_id": 22,
                    "estimate_transit_time_business_days": 8
                }
            ],
            "stock_location": "Extrema",
            "stock_location_external_id": 3
        }
    ],
    "initial_cost": 41.71,
    "combination_id": 164762042,
    "delivery_method": "express",
    "estimate_business_days": 9,
    "estimate_delivery_date": "06/10/20"
}
```

]

```
output = pd.json_normalize(val)
```

Comment: @dfunkako thanks for the answer. I made this, but i got another error " 'str' object has no attribute 'values' when i try to run json_normalize :(